# Migrating SSIS package from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: ssis, package, migrating

Hi I am Migrating SSIS package from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008.
The package ran successfully in sql 2005 using provider "SQLNCLI.1". 
In sql 2008 I have changed the provider to "SQLNCLI10.1"
it gave below error:

Error:SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_ERROR. The requested provider "SQLNCLI.1" is not registered.

But I am using "SQLNCLI10.1" provider in my package as mentioned above. Please suggest me what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Does it run in 2008 if you leave the provider set to SQLNCLI.1?

Comment: No it did not run. But it ran successfully in SQL 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible that you have the connection string in a saved configuration?  The provider is part of the connection string and if you have that in a saved config, it will override the connection string set up manually in the package.  To check if you are using a config, right click on the control surface and select Package Configurations...

To see if this is the problem, uncheck enable package configurations if it is checked.

Comment: Hi William. Thanks for the response.

I tried the above solution by un-checking the enable package configs option. But I got the same error. Without un-checking the option when I ran it in SQL 2005 by changing connection strings it worked corretly by taking the new conn. strings.